# Convert pid_t into NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How would I convert a pid_t instance into a string instance? I know that a pid_t is nothing more than a signed integer, and yet I can't do something like:

```
# suppose appID is already an instance of pid_t
NSString *appStringID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appID];
```

Why does this bring up an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a signed integer, it's just a formatting issue with your NSString:

do this instead:

```
NSString *appStringID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)appID];
```

A format string of "`%@`" implies that you're passing another NSString object in, which an integer (a raw C type) is not.

Comment: It's not specified whether a `pid_t` is an `int` or a `long`.  For portability you should cast it to a `long` and format it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this looking for answer for Swift:

```swift
var pidString = "\(appID)"
```

Comment: Or simply `var pidString = "\(appID)"`